# Resource.designer.cs и аномальное поведение имени файла в Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

У меня есть картинка
[image: Картинка]

Суть в том, что эта картинка скачена через программу, ее имя тоже создано автоматически. При ее добавлении в проект Resource.designer.cs ее не видит, соответственно не добавляется поле в Drawable.
**Нашел проблему методом тыка, она не понятна мне, а именно:
Если я своими собственными руками переименую имя этой картинки на тоже самое "ut_10", то Resource designer все хорошо добавляет, как так, что это? мой мозг сломан, помогите, у меня таких картинок очень много, неужели мне их руками все переименовывать...**

Answer (score 0):

В первую очередь проверьте все ли верно указано в Build Action этих файлов. Во вторую - проверьте правильность добавления в .csproj файле. Там должно быть что-то около

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\image_name.jpg" />
</ItemGroup>
```

для каждой из картинок.

По вашему вопросу: попробуйте выделить все картинки -> Exclude from project. Далее - выберите их снова и -> Include in project. Сбилдите проект.